# How to delete rows in different section of tableview with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delete-row, nsindexpath

I am using this to delete rows in different sections.

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        for i in 0..<sectionArray.count{//Section
            for j in 0..<rowArray.count{//row
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: j, section: i)//indexpath
                self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem? And never call `reloadData` right after `deleteRows`

Comment: this code doesn't work